# Let f will be function $C^{1}$ in near $x^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ then $ f(x) = f(x^{*}) + \int_0^1\nabla{f(x^*+ te)^{T}e \thinspace dt } $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

> Let f will be function $C^{1}$ in near $x^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ then
>   $$ f(x) = f(x^{*}) + \int_0^1\nabla{f(x^*+ te)^{T}e \thinspace dt } 
>  $$

Proof

We use theory of Newtona-Leibnitza integrate: 
$$g(b)- g(a) = \int_a^b g^{'}(x) dx$$
consider a new function: 
$$\gamma: [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R^{N}}$$

$$\gamma(t) = x^{*} + et :[0,1]\mapsto R^{n} $$
and we composition with
$f \circ \gamma :[0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R^{N}} $

$$
    f(\gamma(1))- f(\gamma(0)) 
    = \int_0^1 (f \circ \gamma)^{'} (t) dt
$$
$$
    f(x^{*}+e)- f(x^{*}) 
    = \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))^{'} \gamma^{'}(t) dt
$$
$$
    f(x^{*}+e) = f(x^{*}) 
    + \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))^{'} \gamma^{'}(t) dt
\color{red}{\text{how to prove that: ? } \iff }
$$

$$
    f(x^{*}+e) = f(x^{*}) 
    + \int_0^1 \nabla f(x^{*} + et)e dt
$$
because 
$\gamma^{'}(t) = e$

Comment: What is $e$??? You need something like $e=x-x^*$.

Comment: sory, I forgot add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(t) = f(x^*+t(x-x^*))$.

We have $\phi(1) = \phi(0)+ \int_0^1 \phi'(t)dt$.

We have $\phi'(t) = \langle \nabla f(x^*+t(x-x^*)), x-x^* \rangle$.

Hence $f(x) = f(x^*) + \int_0^1 \langle \nabla f(x^*+t(x-x^*)), x-x^* \rangle dt = \langle \int_0^1  \nabla f(x^*+t(x-x^*)) dt, x-x^* \rangle$.

Comment: Can you explain bit more: 
We have $\phi'(t) = \langle \nabla f(x^*+t(x-x^*)), x-x^* \rangle$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule for differentiating compositions?

Comment: Because $\phi = f \circ g$, where $g(t) = x^*+t(x-x^*)$. Then $D \phi(t) = Df(g(t)) Dg(t)$.

Comment: aa many thanks!